# Remote control wireless helicopter hovering in cruising aircraft, will it move the aircraft with stability

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, air, aircraft

A Mini Toy Helicopter is left for hovering inside the cabin of an Aircraft, while the aircraft is cruising at the speed of 900 Km/h. Helicopter has no contact with the surface of the aircraft.

The Question is... What would happen with the toy helicopter due to the speed of the aircraft?

1: It will be stable, on its position?
2: Or it will move back (slowly or fast)?

Also explain Why?

Comment: I vaguely recall questions about flies in cars. Let me look... [(1)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53475/17609)... [(2)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23787/17609)... [(3)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22960/17609)... [(4)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9526/17609). Etc. OK, they are not all about flies, also toy helicopters. :)

Comment: You could just consider if the helicopter were hovering in still air outside somewhere on the equator of the earth. The air it is in actually moves East at around 1,000 mph, or actually the entire earth is moving about 40,000 mph in its orbit around the sun, but neither you nor the helicopter seem to be bothered by that. Same idea.

Comment: airplane is moving forward in that case and earth has no effect due to gravity....